# Размер h1 для отдельной рубрики

Tags: wordpress

Требуется для отдельно взятой категории-рубрики (wordpress) установить font-size заголовок H1, нужного мне размера?
В моей теме за оглавление поста отвечает класс .post-headline

Применяю следующее:

```
.category-20 h1 {font-size:25px!important;}
.category-20, .post-headline h1 {font-size:25px!important;}
```

Ни чего не работает.

Comment: Может быть, css файл просто закеширован браузером?

Comment: @СергейКоноваловКэш не при делах.